# protractor + cucumber + Typescript failing

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, cucumber, protractor

- Node Version: `4.4.5`
- Protractor Version: `3.3.0`
- Browser(s): `chrome`
- Operating System and Version `Win 7`

I am trying to write protractor + cucumber combination in typescript. My project has a simple feature to open the page and input three fields. I am failing to run protractor. its throwing me below error.

> $ protractor protractor.conf.js
>   [13:40:55] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>
> ### [13:40:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>
> ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
>
> ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (1,30): Cannot find namespace 'protractor'. (2503)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (2,18): Cannot find namespace 'webdriver'. (2503)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (14,21): Cannot find name 'element'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (14,29): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (15,44): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (16,48): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (17,50): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (18,47): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (19,32): Cannot find name 'element'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (19,40): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.page.ts (36,29): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (1,13): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (1,33): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (4,42): Cannot find module 'cucumber-tsflow'. (2307)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (5,19): Cannot find namespace 'cucumber'. (2503)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (10,7): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning. (1219)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (14,13): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning. (1219)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (15,9): Cannot find name 'browser'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (15,21): Cannot find name 'browser'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (16,27): Cannot find name 'element'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (16,35): Cannot find name 'by'. (2304)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (21,13): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning. (1219)
>   ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (26,13): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning. (1219)
>
> ### ..\e2e\features\step_definitions\factory\factory-form.steps.ts (31,13): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning. (1219)
>
> [13:40:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

**protractor.conf.js**

```
require('ts-node/register');

exports.config = {
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,

    exclude: [],

    allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:5001/",

    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ["../e2e/features/step_definitions/factory/*.steps.ts"],
        format: "pretty"
    },

    specs: ['../e2e/features/createfactory.feature'],

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    }
};
```

**factory-form.steps.ts**

```
let chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
let expect = chai.expect;

import {binding, given, when, then} from "cucumber-tsflow";
import Callback = cucumber.CallbackStepDefinition;

import {FactoryFormPageObject} from './factory-form.page';

@binding
class FactoryFormSteps {
    private factoryFormPageObject: FactoryFormPageObject = new FactoryFormPageObject();

    @given(/^I navigate to factory page$/)
    private givenUserClicksFactoryLink(callback: Callback) {
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
        var factoryMenu = element(by.id("factory"));
        factoryMenu.click().then(callback);
    };

    @given(/^I input mandatory fields$/)
    private givenUserInputsMandatoryFields(callback: Callback) {
        callback(null, 'pending');
    };

    @when(/^I click save button$/)
    private whenUserClicksSaveButton(callback: Callback) {
        callback(null, 'pending');
    };

    @then(/^a new factory should be created with the mandatory fields$/)
    private thenFactoryisSaved(callback: Callback) {
        callback(null, 'pending');
    };
}
```

**factory-form.page.ts**

```
import ElementArrayFinder = protractor.ElementArrayFinder;
import Promise = webdriver.promise.Promise;

export class FactoryFormPageObject {
    private form;
    private nameInput;
    private address1Input;
    private countryDropdown;
    private submitButton;
    private goToFactoryLink;

    constructor() {

        this.form = element(by.name('factoryForm'));
        this.nameInput = this.form.element(by.name('factoryName'));
        this.address1Input = this.form.element(by.name('address1'));
        this.countryDropdown = this.form.element(by.name('country'));
        this.submitButton = this.form.element(by.name('save'));
        this.goToFactoryLink = element(by.id('factory'));

    }

    setName(value: string): Promise<void> {
        return this.nameInput.clear().sendKeys(value);
    }

    setAddress1(value: string): Promise<void> {
        return this.address1Input.clear().sendKeys(value);
    }

    setCountry(value: string): Promise<void> {
        return this.selectDropdownbyNum(this.countryDropdown, 1);
    }

    selectDropdownbyNum(element, optionNum): Promise<void> {
        return  element.all(by.tagName('option')).get(optionNum).click();
    };

}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ethos-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.6",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "cucumber": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^0.6.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

I have made my project using Angular-cli (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and I tried to follow https://github.com/samvloeberghs/protractor-gherkin-cucumberjs-angular2.

do i need to do some extra step that protractor will compile the typescript files first? or is there anything i am missing?

Comment: see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5306 . Looks like in tsconfig.json (or somewhere similar) you need compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }, probably because of the reflect-metadata dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is this:

> Cannot find namespace 'protractor'

You need to fix that. You either need to define `protractor` typings globally or

> `import {protractor} from 'protractor'`

I don't know your `tsconfig.js` or `system.config.js` but you essentially have to enable the above to have `tsc` resolve `protractor` module.

Answer (score 0):

Update typescript to 2.0+ and protractor 4.0+ . Make sure you update your global and local version.  Updating typescript to 2.0 should fix it.

Comment: This should be a comment on the original question